# Android API 21 MediaPlayer With RTSP Does not Work Due to Assertion Error

Tags: android, video, streaming, media-player, rtsp

Android decoding of RTSP streams does not “just work”.  We are finding considerable differences in behavior between different stream sources and decoders.  The main cause that we know of at this time is in a native Android library called libstagefright, which seems to be very sensitive to the SDP content returned from the streaming device during setup.  It contains at least two crash bugs that have been very easy to trigger.  These bugs have created an entire market for decoder applications that work around them.

1. SDP content matters

a.  rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov
Known good SDP seems to specify each track fully.  This is the SDP returned from the Big Buck Bunny test stream.  Note that it specifies both a video (m=video) and audio track (m=audio) and that both include ‘rtpmap’ and ‘fmtp’ attributes.

```
v=0
o=- 1462486029327724 1 IN IP4 192.168.0.31
s=LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
i=LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
a=x-qt-text-inf:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50
a=rtpmap:96 MPEG4-GENERIC/12000/2
a=fmtp:96 streamtype=5;profile-level-id=1;mode=AAC-hbr;sizelength=13;indexlength=3;indexdeltalength=3;config=1490
a=control:track1
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 97
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=fmtp:97 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42C01E;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LAHtkDxWhAAAADAEAAAAwDxYuS,aMuMsg==
a=control:track2
```

b.  RTSP from a Camera: rtsp://192.168.34.236/channel1
Missing audio track.  The following SDP record from the webcam in RGB’s lab does not contain an audio track specification.  This causes a segmentation fault in libstagefright.  Here is the SDP:

```
s=LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
i=LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09 a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
a=x-qt-text-inf:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09 m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96 c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:512
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=420028;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0IAKOkBQGcg,aM44gA==
a=control:track1

And here are the Android logs from that crash:
                                                                      --------- beginning of crash
05-05 22:16:43.303 318-9410/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10 in tid 9410 (NuPlayerDriver )
05-05 22:16:43.321 9390-9390/com.ebookfrenzy.videoplayer I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1b8f4410 time:20710760
05-05 22:16:43.407 312-312/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-05 22:16:43.407 312-312/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'qcom/apq8084/apq8084:5.0.2/LRX22G/tom05021823:userdebug/test-keys'
05-05 22:16:43.407 312-312/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
05-05 22:16:43.407 312-312/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
05-05 22:16:43.408 312-312/? I/DEBUG: pid: 318, tid: 9410, name: NuPlayerDriver   >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
05-05 22:16:43.408 312-312/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
05-05 22:16:43.410 913-1038/system_process W/NativeCrashListener: Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 318
05-05 22:16:43.422 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     r0 00000008  r1 b2ffebd0  r2 00000000  r3 b2ffec10
05-05 22:16:43.422 312-312/? E/DEBUG: AM write failure (32 / Broken pipe)
05-05 22:16:43.422 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     r4 b2ffebd0  r5 b2ffebd4  r6 00000008  r7 b2ffec14
05-05 22:16:43.422 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     r8 b2ffec48  r9 00000003  sl b2ffec94  fp 00000000
05-05 22:16:43.422 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     ip b662bb88  sp b2ffeba8  lr b6593e97  pc b6e91022  cpsr 400f0030
05-05 22:16:43.422 312-312/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
05-05 22:16:43.422 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00010022  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::SortedVectorImpl::_indexOrderOf(void const*, unsigned int*) const+5)
05-05 22:16:43.422 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00088e93  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
05-05 22:16:43.422 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00088edd  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MetaData::findData(unsigned int, unsigned int*, void const**, unsigned int*) const+10)
05-05 22:16:43.423 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00089309  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MetaData::findInt32(unsigned int, int*)+16)
05-05 22:16:43.423 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000a3c4d  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::ExtendedUtils::createPCMMetaFromSource(android::sp<android::MetaData> const&)+92)
05-05 22:16:43.423 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0004736d  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so (android::NuPlayer::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+2328)
05-05 22:16:43.423 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000a403  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooperRoster::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+166)
05-05 22:16:43.423 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00009d85  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+220)
05-05 22:16:43.423 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000ef11  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+112)
05-05 22:16:43.423 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000ea81  /system/lib/libutils.so
05-05 22:16:43.423 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00013887  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
05-05 22:16:43.423 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0001187b  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)

The interesting thing is that it’s crashing in attempting to extract audio meta data from a non-existent audio track.

c.  RTSP from a high-end camera: http://192.168.0.190/rtpstream/config1=u
Track declared but not fully specified.  In this stream from the Canon webcam, the video track is declared to be of format 26 which indicates JPEG, but there is no ‘rtpmap’ attribute for that track, and the libstagefright processing exits due to an assertion failure.  Here is the SDP:
v=0
o=- 1462487016542880 1 IN IP4 192.168.0.31
s=LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
i=LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
a=x-qt-text-inf:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.11.09
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 26
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50
a=control:track1
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 97
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50
a=rtpmap:97 PCMU/8000
a=control:track2

And here are the logs from the assertion failure:
                                                       --------- beginning of crash
05-05 22:24:17.492 9439-15880/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 15880 (rtsp)
05-05 22:24:17.600 312-312/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-05 22:24:17.600 312-312/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'qcom/apq8084/apq8084:5.0.2/LRX22G/tom05021823:userdebug/test-keys'
05-05 22:24:17.600 312-312/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
05-05 22:24:17.600 312-312/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
05-05 22:24:17.601 312-312/? I/DEBUG: pid: 9439, tid: 15880, name: rtsp  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
05-05 22:24:17.601 312-312/? I/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
05-05 22:24:17.602 913-1038/system_process W/NativeCrashListener: Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 9439
05-05 22:24:17.614 913-966/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.ebookfrenzy.videoplayer/.VideoPlayerActivity: +927ms
05-05 22:24:17.614 913-966/system_process I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{2c3e43b0 u0 com.ebookfrenzy.videoplayer/.VideoPlayerActivity t37} time:21165053
05-05 22:24:17.635 312-312/? I/DEBUG: Abort message: 'frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/rtsp/ASessionDescription.cpp:217 CHECK(findAttribute(index, key, desc)) failed.'
05-05 22:24:17.635 312-312/? E/DEBUG: AM write failure (32 / Broken pipe)
05-05 22:24:17.635 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00003e08  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
05-05 22:24:17.635 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     r4 b44ffdb8  r5 00000006  r6 00000073  r7 0000010c
05-05 22:24:17.635 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     r8 b423d040  r9 00000001  sl 00000000  fp b44ffae0
05-05 22:24:17.635 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     ip 00003e08  sp b44ff580  lr b6eec0a1  pc b6f0eff4  cpsr 600f0010
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00036ff4  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0001409d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00014cbb  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00011511  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000fc94  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00007805  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+88)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0005e3a1  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so (android::ASessionDescription::getFormatType(unsigned int, unsigned long*, android::AString*, android::AString*) const+80)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0005712d  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so (android::APacketSource::APacketSource(android::sp<android::ASessionDescription> const&, unsigned int)+92)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0004f455  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0005112f  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0000a403  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooperRoster::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+166)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00009d85  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+220)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0000ef11  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+112)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0000ea81  /system/lib/libutils.so
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00013887  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
05-05 22:24:17.636 312-312/? I/DEBUG:     #15 pc 0001187b  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
05-05 22:24:17.671 15841-15841/com.ebookfrenzy.videoplayer I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@171d0b09 time:21165110
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: Why does it not work due to Assert statements or crash in libstagefright library that seems to have a high-use? How can we work around fixing this ?